# How can I parse different types of objects with TextFSM?

Tags: python-textfsm

I want to parse a command out put with TextFSM. But I want to avoid unmatched values in the output. I am not sure if that is even possible with TextFSM.
I have attached the temple, the text to parse, the current output and the desired output below.

TextFSM template:

```
Value PLATFORM (\S+)
Value MODEL (.*)
Value SERIAL (.*)
Value SLOT (\d)
Value DESCR (.*)
Value LOM_STATUS (\S+)
Value LOM_REV (\S+)
 
 
Start
  ^Platform:\s${PLATFORM}
  ^Model:\s${MODEL}
  ^Serial Number:\s${SERIAL} -> Record
  ^LOM\sStatus:\s${LOM_STATUS}
  ^LOM\sFirmware\sRevision:\s${LOM_REV} -> Record
  ^Line\scard\s${SLOT}\smodel:\s${MODEL}
  ^Line\scard\s${SLOT}\stype:\s${DESCR} -> Record
```

Text to parse:

```
Platform: PH-20-00
Model: Check Point 15400
Serial Number: LR7575757575757
CPU Model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3
CPU Frequency: 2400.040 Mhz
Number of Cores: 16
CPU Hyperthreading: Enabled
Number of disks: 2
Disk 1 Model: ST1000NM0033-9ZM173
Disk 1 Capacity: 1.00 TB
Disk 2 Model: ST1000NM0033-9ZM173
Disk 2 Capacity: 1.00 TB
Total Disks size: 2.00 TB
Total Memory: 24576 MB
Memory Slot 1 Size: 8192 MB
Memory Slot 2 Size: 8192 MB
Memory Slot 3 Size: 8192 MB
Power supply 1 name: Power Supply #1
Power supply 1 status: Up
Power supply 2 name: Power Supply #2
Power supply 2 status: Up
LOM Status: Installed
LOM Firmware Revision: 3.43
Number of line cards: 3
Line card 1 model: CPAC-4-10F-B
Line card 1 type: 4 ports 10GbE SFP+ Rev 2.0
Line card 2 model: CPAC-8-1C-B
Line card 2 type: 8 ports 1GbE RJ45 Rev 1.0
Line card 3 model: CPAC-2-10F-B
Line card 3 type: 2 ports 1/10GbE SFP+ Rev 2.0
AC Present: No
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "PLATFORM": "PH-20-00",
    "MODEL": "Check Point 15400",
    "SERIAL": "LR201606001133",
    "SLOT": "",
    "DESCR": "",
    "LOM_STATUS": "",
    "LOM_REV": ""
  },
  {
    "PLATFORM": "",
    "MODEL": "",
    "SERIAL": "",
    "SLOT": "",
    "DESCR": "",
    "LOM_STATUS": "Installed",
    "LOM_REV": "3.43"
  },
  {
    "PLATFORM": "",
    "MODEL": "CPAC-4-10F-B",
    "SERIAL": "",
    "SLOT": "1",
    "DESCR": "4 ports 10GbE SFP+ Rev 2.0",
    "LOM_STATUS": "",
    "LOM_REV": ""
  },
  {
    "PLATFORM": "",
    "MODEL": "CPAC-8-1C-B",
    "SERIAL": "",
    "SLOT": "2",
    "DESCR": "8 ports 1GbE RJ45 Rev 1.0",
    "LOM_STATUS": "",
    "LOM_REV": ""
  },
  {
    "PLATFORM": "",
    "MODEL": "CPAC-2-10F-B",
    "SERIAL": "",
    "SLOT": "3",
    "DESCR": "2 ports 1/10GbE SFP+ Rev 2.0",
    "LOM_STATUS": "",
    "LOM_REV": ""
  }
 ]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  {
    "PLATFORM": "PH-20-00",
    "MODEL": "Check Point 15400",
    "SERIAL": "LR201606001133"
  },
  {
    "LOM_STATUS": "Installed",
    "LOM_REV": "3.43"
  },
  {
    "MODEL": "CPAC-4-10F-B",
    "SERIAL": "",
    "SLOT": "1",
    "DESCR": "4 ports 10GbE SFP+ Rev 2.0"
  },
  {
    "MODEL": "CPAC-8-1C-B",
    "SERIAL": "",
    "SLOT": "2",
    "DESCR": "8 ports 1GbE RJ45 Rev 1.0"
  },
  {
    "MODEL": "CPAC-2-10F-B",
    "SERIAL": "",
    "SLOT": "3",
    "DESCR": "2 ports 1/10GbE SFP+ Rev 2.0"
  }
]
```